# Terraform errors caused by switching workspaces and branches

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I got some errors like:

```
Error: Error creating IAM Role xxxxxxxx: EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name xxxxxxxxx already exists.
status code: 409......

Error: Error creating Security Group: InvalidGroup.Duplicate: The security group 'xxxxx' already exists for VPC 'vpc-xxxxxx'
status code: 400.........

Error: ClientException: Fargate requires task definition to have execution role ARN to support ECR images.
```

Terraform script looks like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "xxxxxxx" {
  name = "xxxxxxx-${terraform.workspace}"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/human-role/xxxxx",
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_security_group" "xxxxxxx" {
  name   = "xxxxx"
  vpc_id = terraform.workspacexxxxxxxxxxx
......
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xxxxxxxxxx" {
  family                   = "xxxxx-${terraform.workspace}"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = "${var.fargate_cpu}"
  memory                   = "${var.fargate_memory}"  

  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
   .....
      }
    ]
  }
]
DEFINITION
}
```

For testing purpose, I switched workspaces and also created a different feature branch, but seems like it's not a good way and even misused terraform, it's causing more issues now.

Has anyone come across this problem before? I'm new to Terraform, would be great if someone can give me some hints.

Comment: What does your Terraform code look like?

Comment: Please see my edit @ydaetskcoR